# unable to acess apache default page from public ip of aws

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, httpd.conf

I gave this code in user data but not able to load any page with the following public IP 35.173.240.157 or when I tried to open a text document.
35.173.240.157/test.html

```
> #!/bin/bash 
> yum install httpd –y
> 
> service httpd start
>
> chkconfig httpd on
echo “<h1> Hi! This is bootstrapping!</h1>”>/var/www/html/test.html
```

[image]
I expect the output that default apache page should be displayed and this text should be accessed
note: I am using ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know where the error is.

So log in to EC2, check if your commands were successfully executed, by running

```
service httpd status
```

if you get an error, httpd was not installed, and that means your file was probably not created, as the directory was not present.

do check that with:

```
ls -lrt /var/www/html
```

EDIT: I learnt that you don't need to be sudo when you're running a bootstrap script.